# Export LDAP schema without data

Tags: ldap, openldap, slapd

For testing purposes, I need a copy of our LDAP server without any personal data.

What is the best way, to export this from an existing OpenLDAP server?

I tried [ldapsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792563/how-do-i-clone-an-openldap-database) and [Apache Directory Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/users-guide/ldap_browser/tools_ldifexport_wizard.html), but I did not find a way to skip actual data (if there is such a thing in LDAP).

Answer (score 3):

Configuration for reasonably modern versions of OpenLDAP are accessible at the `cn=config` suffix, provided you're authenticating with a dn that has read privileges to it. If local root is also the rootdn you should be able to dump the ldif via `sudo ldapsearch -H ldapi:/// -Y EXTERNAL -b cn=config`

If that method does not work, within the filesystem these files will likely be under `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/`. If your system is older the configuration will be in a single file, likely `/etc/openldap/slapd.conf`.